# parsing json for dashing dashboard widget

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, dashing

I am trying the code below, I use a while because I dont know the length of the array.  but I get this errors

this api returns the **JSON below**, I would like to only have a map with label, nb_uniq_visitors

Look at the JSON string .

```
[
  {
    "label": "Australia",
    "nb_uniq_visitors": 1,
    "nb_visits": 1,
    "nb_actions": 2,
    "nb_users": 0,
    "max_actions": 2,
    "sum_visit_length": 519,
    "bounce_count": 0,
    "nb_visits_converted": 0,
    "code": "au",
    "logo": "plugins\/UserCountry\/images\/flags\/au.png",
    "segment": "countryCode==au",
    "logoWidth": 16,
    "logoHeight": 11
  },
  {
    "label": "United States",
    "nb_uniq_visitors": 1,
    "nb_visits": 1,
    "nb_actions": 1,
    "nb_users": 0,
    "max_actions": 1,
    "sum_visit_length": 0,
    "bounce_count": 1,
    "nb_visits_converted": 0,
    "code": "us",
    "logo": "plugins\/UserCountry\/images\/flags\/us.png",
    "segment": "countryCode==us",
    "logoWidth": 16,
    "logoHeight": 11
  }
]
```

**scheduler caught exception:**

> no implicit conversion of String into Integer
>   /home//mixed_dashboard/jobs/visitsbycountry.rb:25:in `[]'
>   /home//mixed_dashboard/jobs/visitsbycountry.rb:25:in`block in '
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in
>   `call'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in`
>   trigger_block'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:204:in
>   `block in trigger'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in`
>   call'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in
>   `block in trigger_job'

--------------------------------------------------- CODE BELOW ----------------------

```
   require 'rubygems'
   require 'net/http'
   require 'json'

   server = ""

   SCHEDULER.every '30s', :first_in => 0 do |job|  


   url = URI.parse("#{server}")
   http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)  
   request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri)
   response = http.request(request)
   j = JSON[response.body]

   # Convert to JSON

   countries = []
   $i=0
   $num = 5

    while $i < $num do 

      country_name = j["label"]
      country_visits = j["nb_unique_visits"]
      countryHash = {country_name => country_visits}
      countries.push(countryHash)
      $i+=1
    end 


   send_event('buzzwords', { items: countries }) 
   end
```

Comment: First of all you have infinite `while` loop.

Comment: Yeah I am new to ruby, but I taught that it would end when i is 5 ?

Comment: I don't see where do you increment `$i`?

Comment: your right let me add that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  country_visits = j["nb_unique_visits"].to_i
```